# Sigaction handler in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, process, signals

We have an assignment to explain this text of code. My only problem is understanding the handle_signal function, why did we use 2 new sigaction and then used "old_treatment" with "rien"?

```
#define DELAY 1
#define NB_ITERATIONS 60
void handle_signal (int num_signal){
    struct sigaction rien, old_ treatment;
    printf ("Signal %d => ", num_signal);
    printf ("I have received a SIGTSTP.\n");
    rien.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    rien.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset (&rien.sa_mask);
    sigaction (SIGTSTP, &rien, &old_ treatment);
    printf ("Then I sleep....\n");
    kill (getpid(), SIGSTOP);
    printf ("They wakes me?\n");
    Sigaction (SIGTSTP, &old_ treatment, NULL);
    printf ("Here we go again!\n");
}

int main (void){
    struct sigaction a;
    int i;
    a.sa_handler = handle_signal;
    sigemptyset (&a.sa_mask);
    sigaction (SIGTSTP, &a, NULL);
    for (i = 1; i < NB_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    sleep (DELAY);
    printf ("%d", i % 10);
    fflush (stdout);}
    printf ("End\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You can only safely make async-signal-safe function calls from within a signal handler.  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03

Comment: Is there a difference between `sigaction` and `Sigaction`?

Comment: I see no `case`, and no `switch`

Comment: @WeatherVane `Sigaction` is how you call the function if you're calling it at the beginning of a sentence. :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I re-edited the whole thing

Comment: @Barmar they are all at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't see the use in the code before, I thought you were just making a snarky comment about the title.

Comment: @TimRandall He's edited that out of the question, but now I think he was asking why it switched from lowercase `sigaction` to mixed case `Sigaction`, not about `case` and `switch` statements.

Comment: It seems like you have a bunch of typos. I `Sigaction` is probably a typo for `sigaction`, the initial capital was not intended. And there shouldn't be a space in `old_ treatment`.

Comment: It's just from copy and paste, and that doesn't even affect the code, come on guys

Comment: Yes, but the point about the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that we don't have to fumble around asking whether a typo is a real typo or an accidental typo, or whether the code is the *actual* code or only *resembles* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this is to temporarily change the action for `SIGTSTP`, then restore it back.

```
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &rien, &old_handler);
```

sets it to the default action, and saves the previous action in `old_handler`.

Then it sends itself a `SIGSTOP` signal to actually suspend the process.

When that returns, it means that the process has been continued, so it puts back the old action with:

```
sigaction(SIGTSTOP, &old_handler, NULL);
```

It's not clear why this is needed, though. It would make more sense if it suspended the process by sending a `SIGTSTP` signal rather than `SIGSTOP`. In that case, it needs to set the default action, otherwise it would just recurse infinitely.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude!